# How to remove ToolStripButton´s checked blue rectangle

Tags: vb.net

I have a ToolStripButton with CheckOnClick property set to true. When it is clicked the Checked property becomes true and a blue border appears surrounding the button and it remains there as long as in the checked state. I want to remove this border, because I change the background color myself to indicate that the button is selected. How could I do that? I tried with ToolStripRenderer but I could not found the way.

Comment: Move the focus to another control/or the form in the click event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn´t work. I have several such buttons and that border appears in all those that have its property Checked set to true, no matter where the focus is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing your own `ToolStripRenderer` should give you what you're looking for. I'm not real familiar with using these, but I was able able to get the functionality I believe you are looking for with the following implementation.

```
Public Class BorderlessToolStripRenderer
    Inherits Windows.Forms.ToolStripProfessionalRenderer

    Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderButtonBackground(e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs)
        Dim button = TryCast(e.Item, ToolStripButton)

        If (button IsNot Nothing AndAlso button.Checked) Then
            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Yellow)
        Else
            MyBase.OnRenderButtonBackground(e)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

I'm assuming you're using `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer`, so I inherited that one and just omit the standard background rendering when the button is in the checked state. This keeps the mouse over indicator, but omits the border when checked and instead renders a yellow background.

And of course, to use this class, you just need to set the `Renderer` property on your `ToolStrip` like this

```
Me.ToolStrip1.Renderer = New BorderlessToolStripRenderer()
```

Comment: Thanks Jason! It worked, but now I have a new crazy problem. the Graphcis.Clear method works only with predefined system colors (at least that says in documentation), but I want to set the background color to Color.FromArgb(227, 227, 227) (it is a requirement), that makes look the button like pressed with a 3d effect. None of the predefined constants in Color structure approximates that color. I just simply want to set the background with my color without that blue border but it is showing as a titan´s work ;)

Comment: Finally I set CheckOnClick to false and made my own Shadows Checked property in a derived class.

Comment: Hey Daniel. Sounds like you've got a solution that works for you, but just so you know, replacing the clear call with `e.Graphics.Clear(Color.FromArgb(227, 227, 227))` should work fine. I tried it and it worked.

Comment: No way, there must be some setting or something like that. Thanks anyway!